# Generating functions and the Riemann Zeta Function

Tags: generating-functions, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

The generating function for the terms of the harmonic series:

$\frac{1}{n}$

is $-\ln(1 - x)$.

Does an ordinary generating function exist for the terms of the zeta function $\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}$
for any $ s > 1$?

That is, does there exist any function $f(x)$ that can be expressed in terms of elementary functions such that $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}x^n$ for some $s > 1$?

I'm assuming that such a function in fact does not exist.  Can this be proven to be the case?

Comment: Did you hear about polylogarithms ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is an answer to the initial question (asking for a generating function of $\zeta(s)$) :

- $−\ln(1−x)$ is the generating function of $\ \frac 1n$.
- $-\frac{\ln(1−x)}{1-x}$ is the generating function of the [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) $\ H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1k$

The generating function of the [generalized harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalization) $\ H_{n,s}:=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1{k^s}\ $ is given by :
$$\frac{\operatorname{Li}_s(x)}{1-x}$$
with $\operatorname{Li}_s$ the [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Should you simply want $\ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^s}=\operatorname{Li}_s(x)\ $ then dot dot's answer is right of course !

Note that a generating function for $\zeta(n)$ is known as the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Taylor_series) :
$$\psi(1+x)=-\gamma-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \zeta(n+1)\;(-x)^n$$
while the [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Reflection_formula) allows to get the [even values](https://oeis.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Generating_function_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function_for_nonnegative_even_integers) of $\zeta$ directly as :
$$\pi\;x\;\cot(\pi\;x)=-2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \zeta(2n)\;x^{2n}$$

A [generating function for the polylogarithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4185891/21783) was obtained too :
$$z\,\Phi(z, 1, 1-x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\;\operatorname{Li}_{n+1}(z)\;x^n$$
using the [Lerch zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function) $\displaystyle\;\Phi(z, s, \alpha) := \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac { z^k} {(k+\alpha)^s}$.

Comment: I've edited my question, I of course meant the generating function for the _terms_ of the harmonic series, not for the harmonic series itself (which is divergent as you say.)

Comment: @Bitrex: So that you wanted the generating function of $n^{-s}$ in fact... Note that a generating function for $\zeta(n)$ is known : the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Taylor_series) and that a [generating function for the even values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Reflection_formula) of $\zeta$ is simply $\pi\cot(\pi\;x)$.

Comment: Nice illustration and summary.

Comment: Thanks @Mhenni ! I must admit that this was done too for my convenience : I searched these generating functions and  links more than once!

Comment: And what about  [The generating function of the polylogarithm.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4185786/622884)?
Or the generatign funciton for the generalised harmonic harmonic numbers BUT in powers of the order, instead of powers of its number of terms?

Answer (score 6):

The function you are looking for is the Li$_s(z)$, the polylogarithm.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It looks like the polylogarithm can only be expressed in terms of elementary functions for integers $s < 1$, so for $s > 1$ it seems the answer to my question is indeed negative.