# Prove $\int^\infty_0\frac x{e^x-1}dx=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, integration

I know that $$\int^\infty_0\frac x{e^x-1}dx=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$ For substituting $u=2$ into $$\zeta(u)\Gamma(u)=\int^\infty_0\frac{x^{u-1}}{e^x-1}dx$$

However, I suspect that there is an easier proof, maybe by the use of complex analysis. I haven't learnt the [zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) yet. All I know is the above formula and $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. Can we can use the above integral to find out some of the $\zeta$'s value?

Comment: A [related technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108248/prove-int-01-frac-ln-x-x-1-d-x-sum-1-infty-frac1n2/279065#279065).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**UPDATED**
You may indeed use contour integration as nicely exposed in [Ablowitz and Fokas  "Complex Variables" p. $244$](http://books.google.com/books?id=SFqbV3i3hO0C&pg=PA244).

The idea is to evaluate $\;\displaystyle I(p):=PV \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac {e^{px}}{1-e^x}dx,\quad(0<p<1)\quad$ using the contour :

[image: contour]

The integrals at the right and left side vanish as $R\to +\infty$ and the four bottom and top horizontal lines will add the contribution :
$$\left(\int_{-R}^{-\epsilon_1}+\int_{\epsilon_1}^R\right)\frac{e^{px}}{1-e^x}dx+e^{2\pi ip}\left(\int_{R}^{-\epsilon_2}+\int_{\epsilon_2}^{-R}\right)\frac{e^{px}}{1-e^x}dx$$
that is (as $\;R\to +\infty$ and $\epsilon_i\to 0$) :
$$\tag{1}\left(1-e^{2\pi ip}\right)PV \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{px}}{1-e^x}dx$$while the semi-circular contours will give, as $\epsilon_1 \to 0^+$ and $\epsilon_2 \to 0^+$ :

\begin{align}
\tag{2}\lim_{\epsilon_1\to 0}\int_{C\epsilon_1}\frac{e^{pz}}{1-e^z}dz&=-i\pi\left(\frac{e^{pz}}{-e^z}\right)_{z=0}=i\pi\\
\tag{3}\lim_{\epsilon_2\to 0}\int_{C\epsilon_2}\frac{e^{pz}}{1-e^z}dz&=-i\pi\left(\frac{e^{pz}}{-e^z}\right)_{z=2\pi i}=i\pi\,e^{2\pi i p}\\
\end{align}

Since no singularity appears in its inside the whole contour will have an integral of value $0$ equal to the sum of $(1),\;(2)$ and $(3)$. This gives :
$$I(p)=PV \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac {e^{px}}{1-e^x}dx=-i\pi \frac{1+\,e^{2\pi i p}}{1-\,e^{2\pi i p}}$$
or simply :
$$\tag{4} \boxed{\displaystyle I(p)=\pi \cot( \pi p)}$$
Now $(4)$ multiplied by $p$ should give Euler's [generating function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402941/generating-functions-and-the-riemann-zeta-function/402988#402988) for $\zeta($even$)$ :
$$\tag{5}\displaystyle\pi\;p\;\cot(\pi\;p)=1-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \zeta(2n)\;p^{2n}$$
which allows to find $\zeta(2n)$ just by using the expansion of $\pi\,x\;\cot(\pi\,x)$ :
$$\tag{6}\pi\,x\;\cot(\pi\,x)=1-2\left(\frac {\pi^2}6x^2+\frac{\pi^4}{90}x^4+\frac{\pi^6}{945}x^6+\cdots\right)$$

Since we had an integral from $0$ to $+\infty$ and not a Cauchy principal value from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ it will be convenient to  rewrite $I(p)$ as :

\begin{align}
\tag{7}I(p)-\frac 1p&=\pi \cot( \pi p)-\frac 1p=-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \zeta(2n)\;p^{2n-1}\\ 
&=PV \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac {e^{px}}{1-e^x}dx-\int_0^\infty e^{-px}dx\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{\epsilon}^\infty \frac {e^{px}}{1-e^x}-e^{-px}dx+\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon} \frac {e^{py}}{1-e^y}dy\\
(\text{setting}\;\;y:=-x)\;\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{\epsilon}^\infty \frac {e^{px}}{1-e^x}-e^{-px}+\frac {e^{-px}e^x}{(1-e^{-x})e^x}dx\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{\epsilon}^\infty \frac {e^{px}}{1-e^x}+\frac {e^{-px}e^x-e^{-px}(e^x-1)}{e^x-1}dx\\
\end{align}
with the neat result :
$$\tag{8}\boxed{\displaystyle I(p)-\frac 1p= \int_0^\infty \frac {e^{px}-e^{-px}}{1-e^x}dx}$$

This integral may be used to obtain the coefficients of $p^{2n-1}$ in $(7)$ since :
$$\left(\frac d{dp}\right)^{2n-1} \left(I(p)-\frac 1p\right)=\int_0^\infty \frac {x^{2n-1}\left(e^{px}+e^{-px}\right)}{1-e^x}dx$$
with the limit as $p\to 0$ given by :
$$\int_0^\infty \frac {x^{2n-1}\;2}{1-e^x}dx=-2\,(2n-1)!\,\zeta(2n)$$
corresponding to the classical formula for $n$ positive integer :
$$\tag{9}\zeta(2n)\Gamma(2n)=\int^\infty_0\frac{x^{2n-1}}{e^x-1}dx$$

Comment: Nice figure! (+1)

Comment: Hmmm from the book of course (I'll transmit your vote ! ;-)). Of course your classical method is faster...

Comment: Well, looks nice anyway.  And kudos to the illustration of a Cauchy principal value.

Comment: Thanks for that and your excellent contributions @Ron !

Comment: @Ron: I just found a more direct variant of my answer in your [Greatest Hits](http://stackexchange.moderatenerd.com/2013/05/18/unusual-contour-to-evaluate-a-real-integral/) !

Comment: Well, how interesting.  So it seems that this repository has some use after all.  Thanks, man!

Comment: Dear Raymond, Maybe I could please ask you to elaborate as to how you get (2) & (3). I know you showed how for the half circle you get "half" a residue here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478534/two-questions-regarding-mathrm-li-from-edwards. But that example is in a nice convenient form with the $\frac{C_{-1}}{z-z_0}$ of a Laurent series. So how do you get the terms in the ( ) in each of (2) and (3)? I tried using $z = \epsilon e^{i \theta}$, but that got pretty messy and is far from the simplicity of your terms. Also looked at the link in Ron's blog where he uses $z$ as I mentioned

Comment: so am unable to get his results as well. Thanks very much for your consideration. All the best,

Comment: @96Tears: Hi Andrew. We have two clockwise semi-circular contours so that the residue formula $\,\displaystyle 2\pi i \sum_j \operatorname{Res}\left(\frac {N(z)}{D(z)};z_j\right)$ becomes $\,\displaystyle-\pi i \operatorname{Res}\left(\frac {N(z)}{D(z)};z_0\right)$. Now $N(z):=e^{p\,z}$ and $D(z):=1-e^z$ are both analytic at $z_0=0$ (or $z_0=2\pi i$) with $D(z)$ having a zero of order $1$ at $z_0$ (i.e. $\displaystyle D(z)=(z-z_0)D'(z_0)+\frac {(z-z_0)^2}{2!}D''(z_0)+\cdots$). The residue will then be $\,\displaystyle \frac {N(z_0)}{D'(z_0)}=\frac {e^{p\,z_0}}{-e^{z_0}}$ as wished. Cheers,

Comment: Thanks for you help. All the best, Andrew

Comment: Thanks for the corrections @WangWeixuan!

Answer (score 27):

The standard way of attacking this integral is to Taylor expand the denominator:

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{x^{u-1}}{e^x-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} dx\, x^{u-1} \, e^{-(k+1) x}  = \Gamma(u) \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+1)^u} = \Gamma(u) \zeta(u)$$

I really don't know what insight you would gleam by using a contour integral in the complex plane.  You could use a keyhole contour, and the you would get residues at integers along the imaginary axis so that you will recover the result above.  But the method above is far easier and more intuitive.

Comment: Check [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108248/prove-int-01-frac-ln-x-x-1-d-x-sum-1-infty-frac1n2/279065#279065).

Comment: Dear Ron, Could I please trouble you for a hint as to what looks how to isolate $e^{-kx}$ outside the integral so you have $\Gamma(u)$ times the summation. Actually I fear that posing this question is naive. But that's what it looks like. Actually, probably much better is a hint how to get from the second expression to the third. Thanks very much. With regards, Andrew

Comment: Thanks, Ron. As you know, you are a key All-Pro on my fantasy math team. All the best, Andrew

Comment: @96Tears aka Andrew: yes, my apologies.

Answer (score 9):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{\infty}{x \over \expo{x} - 1}\,\dd x}=
\int_{x\ =\ 0}^{x\ \to\ \infty}x\,\dd\bracks{\ln\pars{1 - \expo{-x}}}
=-\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{1 - \expo{-x}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-nx}\,\dd x
=\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-x}\,\dd x}^{\ds{=\ 1}}\
=\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}}=\color{#00f}{\large{\pi^{2} \over 6}}
\end{align}

Comment: This is efficient and straightforward.  +1

Answer (score 6):

Let $$f(z) = \frac{z}{e^z-1}$$
$f$ has poles at $z =  2 \pi i n$ where $n \in \mathbb Z$ and $n \neq 0$.  Let $C$ be the rectangular contour with vertices at $0, R, R+i\pi$ and $i\pi$ but indented at 0.  Because the residue is $0$ there, the indentation does not add to the value of the integral.

Then, as $R \to \infty$:

$$0=\oint_C f(z)\, dz = \int_{0}^\infty f(z)\, dz-\int_0^\infty f(z+\pi i)\,dz-i\int_0^\pi f(iz)\,dz+\pi^2=\\
\int_{0}^\infty f(z)\, dz+\int_0^\infty \frac{z+\pi i}{e^z+1}\,dz+\int_0^\pi \frac{z}{e^{iz}-1}\,dz
$$

Taking the real parts of both sides yeilds

$$0 = \int_{0}^\infty f(z)\, dz+\int_{0}^\infty \frac{z}{e^z+1}\, dz-\int_0^\pi \frac{x}{2}\,dz$$

so

$$\frac{\pi^2}{4}=\int_{0}^\infty f(z)\, dz+\int_{0}^\infty \frac{z}{e^z+1}\, dz$$

By summing and integrating both series as was done by [Ron Gordon](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/472721/27624), we find

$$I=\int_{0}^\infty f(z)\, dz=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$
$$J=\int_{0}^\infty f(z)\, dz=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2} = \frac{I}{2}$$

and therefore

$$\frac{\pi^2}{4}=I+\frac{I}{2}$$

therefore

$$I=\int_{0}^\infty f(z)\, dz = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Answer (score 2):

An elementary proof:

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{e^x-1}dx& =\frac43\int_0^\infty  \frac{x }{e^x-1}dx -\frac13\int_0^\infty { \frac{x }{e^x-1} } \overset{x\to 2x}{dx} \\
&= \frac23 \int_0^\infty \frac{x}{\sinh x}dx
=\frac23\int_{0}^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{y\  e^x}{1+(e^{2x}-1)y^2}dy\ dx\\
&=\frac\pi 3\int_0^1 \frac1{\sqrt{1-y^2}}dy = \frac{\pi^2}6
\end{align}

Comment: Integral representation of zeta function: $\displaystyle \Gamma\left(2\right)\zeta\left(2\right)$.