# How do we calculate improper integrals of the form $ \int\limits_0^\infty \frac{x^{n}}{e^{x} \pm 1} \mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: calculus, integration

It follows that  $ \int\limits_0^\infty \frac{x^{3}}{e^{x} -  1} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi^{4}}{15},~ \int\limits_0^\infty \frac{x^{3}}{e^{x} +  1} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{7 \pi^{4}}{120},~ \int\limits_0^\infty \frac{x^{5}}{e^{x} -  1} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{8 \pi^{6}}{63},~ \int\limits_0^\infty \frac{x^{2}}{e^{x} -  1} \mathrm{d}x = 2 \zeta (3).$

How did we get those results?

Comment: See Ron Gordon's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472687/prove-int-infty-0-frac-xex-1dx-frac-pi26/472721#472721).

Comment: Here is the [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108248/prove-int-01-frac-ln-x-x-1-d-x-sum-1-infty-frac1n2/279065#279065).

Comment: Thanks a lot. And it also works when the denominator is of the form $e^{u}-1$.

Comment: The "$\large +$" integrals can be expressed in terms of the "$\large -$" integrals. So, you just need the "$\large -$" integrals.