# $\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{e^x-1} dx$ with series

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I've been looking at the following integral, and trying to solve it through series:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{e^x-1} dx$$

I tried expanding out $e^x-1$:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{x+x^2/2!+x^3/3!+x^4/4!+\cdots} dx$$

but I do not know how to continue from there; I feel like it would have something to do with long division, but I don't know how.

I also tried the substitution

$$t=e^x-1$$
$$dt=e^xdx$$
$$x=\ln(1+t)$$

So after multiplying the integrand by $1 = e^x/e^x$ and substituting I got

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+t)}{t(1+t)}dt$$

I tried using series as well, but I was stuck after

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{t-t^2/2+t^3/3-t^4/4+\cdots}{t(1+t)}dt$$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t+1}-\frac{t}{2(t+1)}+\frac{t^2}{3(t+1)}-\frac{t^3}{4(t+1)}+\cdots dt$$

I know that it is supposed to equal $\frac {\pi^2}{6}$, so I know that after doing everything it should come out to $\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\cdots$, but I do not know how to get there.

Thanks!

P.s. Wolfram Alpha gives a closed form for the antiderivative of $\frac{x}{e^x-1}$ as $\operatorname{Li}_2(e^x)-\frac{x^2}{2}+x\ln(1-e^x)+c$

Comment: We have $\frac{1}{e^x - 1} = \frac{1}{e^x} \frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}$ and $y = e^{-x} < 1$ if $x>0$ so we can instead try to expand $\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}} = \frac{1}{1-y} = 1+y+y^2+\ldots$ using the geometrical series.

Comment: In general, $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{e^x-1}~dx ~=~ n!~\zeta(n+1),$$ and $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{e^x+1}~dx ~=~ n!~\eta(n+1).$$ See the [Riemann $\zeta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) and [Dirichlet $\eta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) function for more information.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of trying to expand the denominator, try instead to expand the full fraction $\frac{1}{e^x-1}$ in a series. We have

$$\frac{1}{e^x-1} = e^{-x}\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}$$

Now if $x>0$ then $e^{-x}<1$ so we can expand in a geometrical series

$$\frac{1}{e^x-1} = e^{-x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-kx} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-kx}$$

This gives the integral

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{e^x-1}\,{\rm d}x = \int_0^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty xe^{-kx}\,{\rm d}x \\= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty xe^{-kx}\,{\rm d}x  = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}\int_0^\infty (kx)e^{-kx}\,{\rm d}(kx)  = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}\int_0^\infty ye^{-y}\,{\rm d}y $$

where the switching of the summation and integration is justified by [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem); see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/when-can-a-sum-and-integral-be-interchanged) for more details. The final integral can be evaluated using integration by parts.

The same series approach can be used to compute the integral $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}{\rm d}x = \Gamma(s)\zeta(s)$ where $\Gamma$ is the [$\Gamma$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) and $\zeta$ is the [Riemann $\zeta$-function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function)

For an alternative way of deriving the result using contour integration, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472687/prove-int-infty-0-frac-xex-1dx-frac-pi26).

Comment: You don't really need to use the Gamma function, you just need to integrate by parts to show that $\int_0^\infty xe^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x=1$. Then each integral, by substitution is $\frac1{k^2}$.

Comment: @robjohn Yes of course. I guess I was thinking about the general zeta integral $\frac{x^s}{e^x-1}$ when writing it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 6):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{e^x-1}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_1^\infty\frac{\log(x)}{x(x-1)}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=-\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)}{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}\\
&=-\int_0^1\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^1\frac{x^{k-1}}{k}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{4}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\tag{5}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}6\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: Substitute $x\mapsto\log(x)$
$(2)$: Substitute $x\mapsto\frac1x$
$(3)$: Substitute $x\mapsto1-x$
$(4)$: Expand the series for $\log(1-x)$
$(5)$: Integrate each term
$(6)$: $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}6$