# Stirling's Formula, Remainder Term

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function, residue-calculus

With reference to the Series and Product Development chapter of Ahlfors' complex analysis text (Page 201-205), after deriving Stirling's formula $$\Gamma(z)=\sqrt{2\pi}z^{z-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-z}e^{J(z)},$$ where $$J(z)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{z}{\eta^2+z^2}\log\frac{1}{1-e^{-2\pi\eta}}d\eta,$$ it is noted that the remainder $J(z)$ can be expressed as $$J(z)=\frac{C_1}{z}+\frac{C_2}{z^3}+...+\frac{C_k}{z^{2k-1}}+J_k(z)$$ with coefficients $$C_{\nu}=(-1)^{\nu-1}\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty}\eta^{2\nu-1}\log\frac{1}{1-e^{-2\pi\eta}}d\eta.$$ Subsequently, it states that the coefficients $C_\nu$ are connected with the Bernoulli numbers (Asserting that this can be proved by means of residues) by $$C_\nu=(-1)^{\nu-1}\frac{1}{(2\nu-1)2\nu}B_\nu.$$ How is the last statement proved using the calculus of residues?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try a [keyhole contour](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8d/Keyhole_contour.svg/2000px-Keyhole_contour.svg.png). It may also be useful to note that the Bernoulli numbers have a generating function (see equation (2) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html)). Integration by parts may also be helpful...

Comment: The proper term is $C_k=\frac{B_{2k}}{2k(2k-1)}$. By $J_k(z)$, do you mean $O\!\left(\frac1{z^{2k+1}}\right)$?

Comment: Yes, $J_k(z)$ is equivalent to $O(\frac{1}{z^{2k+1}})$. The book states that $C_\nu=(-1)^{\nu-1}\frac{1}{(2\nu-1)2\nu}B_\nu$; is this then an error in Ahlfor's text?

Comment: In any case, how would this be proved? @robjohn

Comment: I don't know how to do it by residues, but I know how to do it using the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula.

Comment: I don't mean to bother you; however, can you kindly demonstrate this method? @robjohn

Comment: How would one determine the residue of such a function? @Semiclassical

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This method does not use residues, but it does give an answer.

The [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) says that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^nf(k)
&=\int_0^n f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x+C+\frac12f(n)+\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}f^{(2k-1)}(n)+O\!\left(f^{(2m+1)}(n)\right)
\end{align}
$$
Plugging in $f(x)=\log(x)$, where $f^{(2k-1)}(n)=\frac{(2k-2)!}{n^{2k-1}}$, gives
$$
\begin{align}
\log(n!)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k)\\
&=n\log(n)-n+C+\frac12\log(n)+\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{B_{2k}}{2k(2k-1)}\frac1{n^{2k-1}}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^{2m+1}}\right)\\
\end{align}
$$
where [Stirling's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) tells us that $C=\frac12\log(2\pi)$.

That is,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\begin{align}
J(n)
&=\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{B_{2k}}{2k(2k-1)}\frac1{n^{2k-1}}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^{2m+1}}\right)\\
&=\frac1{12n}-\frac1{360n^3}+\frac1{1260n^5}-\frac1{1680n^7}+\frac1{1188n^9}+O\left(\frac1{n^{11}}\right)
\end{align}}
$$

---

**A Note on the Constant**

Note that $C=\frac12\log(2\pi)=-\zeta'(0)$, which can be derived from the fact that [the constant for the sum of $k^\alpha$ is $\zeta(-\alpha)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/162426):
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^\alpha-1}{\alpha}\\
&=\frac1\alpha\left(\frac{n^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}-n+\frac{n^\alpha}2+\zeta(-\alpha)+O\!\left(\alpha n^{\alpha-1}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac1\alpha\left(n\frac{1+\alpha\log(n)}{\alpha+1}-n+\frac{1+\alpha\log(n)}2+O\!\left(\alpha^2n\log(n)^2\right)+\zeta(-\alpha)+O\!\left(\alpha n^{\alpha-1}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac1\alpha\left(\vphantom{\frac12}\right.n\frac{\alpha\log(n)-\alpha}{\alpha+1}+\frac{\alpha\log(n)}2+O\!\left(\alpha^2n\log(n)^2\right)+\zeta(-\alpha)\underbrace{\ -\zeta(0)\ \ }_{\frac12}+O\!\left(\alpha n^{\alpha-1}\right)\left.\vphantom{\frac12}\right)\\
\end{align}
$$
which, upon sending $a\to0$, gives
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k)=n\log(n)-n+\frac12\log(n)\underbrace{\ -\zeta'(0)\ \ }_{\frac12\log(2\pi)}+O\!\left(n^{-1}\right)
$$

Answer (score 6):

Using partial integration, the integral can be expressed as $$C_{\nu}=(-1)^{\nu-1}\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty}\eta^{2\nu-2}\log\frac{1}{1-e^{-2\pi\eta}}d\eta=\frac{2(-1)^{\nu-1}}{2\nu-1} \int_0^\infty \eta^{2\nu-1} (e^{2 \pi \eta}-1)^{-1} \mathrm{d} \eta .$$ As such, by using the identity $$\zeta(2\nu)\Gamma(2\nu)=\int^\infty_0\frac{x^{2\nu-1}}{e^x-1}dx,$$ which is a result in the calculus of residues ([See here] [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472687/prove-int-infty-0-frac-xex-1dx-frac-pi26/472721#472721)), the latter integral can be expressed as:$$\frac{2}{2\nu-1} \int_0^\infty \eta^{2\nu-1} (e^{2 \pi \eta}-1)^{-1} \mathrm{d} \eta=\frac{2}{2\nu-1}  \frac{(2 \nu-1)!}{(2 \pi)^{2 \nu}} \zeta(2 \nu).$$Finally, using the relation
$$\zeta(2 \nu) = \frac{(-1)^{\nu+1} B_{2 \nu} (2 \pi)^{2 \nu}}{2 (2 \nu)!},$$the result follows at once, i.e., $C_\nu=\frac{(-1)^{\nu+1}B_{2\nu}}{2\nu(2\nu-1)}$.