# Cotangent in integral form

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, euler-product

Could you help me to establish the following relation, without going through the Eulerian development
$\displaystyle \pi \operatorname{cotan}(\pi z) = \frac{1}{z} + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left( \frac{1}{z+n} + \frac{1}{z-n} \right)$ :
$$\pi \operatorname{cotan}(\pi z) = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{e^{(1-z)t} - e^{tz}}{e^t-1} dt. \quad 0<\Re(z)<1$$

Comment: A related proof using contour integration can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/472762/549773).

Answer (score 1):

Hoping that you do enjoy hypergeometric functions
$$I=\int\frac{e^{(1-z)t} - e^{tz}}{e^t-1} \,dt$$
$$ I=\frac {e^{-t z} \, _2F_1\left(1,-z;1-z;e^t\right)+e^{t z} \,
   _2F_1\left(1,z;z+1;e^t\right)-e^{-t z} } z$$

$$J=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{(1-z)t} - e^{tz}}{e^t-1} \,dt=\psi (-z)-\psi (z)-\frac{1}{z}=\pi  \cot (\pi  z)$$