# To Evaluate $\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac{1}{r^2}$ using limit as a sum method

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits

I have recently learnt to find some limits and values of some series using integration. This is called as evaluating series and limits using **limit as a sum** in my textbook.

Now, I tried to derive this series using what I learnt. (It is not part of my textbook. I was just doing this for my own fun):

$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac{1}{r^2}= \frac{π^2}{6}$$

Here is what I did :

Let $S = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{r^2}$

Using change of variable of $n\to n^2$ and $r\to r^2$, call $n^2 = x$ and $r^2 = y$, we have :

$$S=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\sum_{y=1}^x\frac{x}{y}$$

Now using limit as a sum formula, we have :

$$S = \int_0^1\frac{1}{x}dx=\infty$$

Of course this is wrong.

Where did I went wrong? Can you provide a correct proof of this series using this **limit as a sum integration method**?

(There is a famous question of this series on this site but on the answers to that, I didn't find a solution involving limit as a sum method. Hence my question is different.)

Comment: The usual approach is here : Fourier-series.

Comment: This sum is fairly complicated to compute directly.

Comment: @Peter Thanks. Unfortunately, I hadn't learnt fourier series as it is high level mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

In the equation:$$S=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\sum_{y=1}^x\frac{x}{y}$$The index of the sum should've been $\sqrt{y}$, which is a bit complicated to work with.

Comment: If we plug back our substitution values, we get : $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\sum_{y=1}^x\frac{x}{y}=$$\lim_{n^2\to \infty} \sum_{r^2 = 1}^n^2 \frac{1}{r^2}$

Comment: @An_Elephant Yes, you are right. This is why the index should've been $\sqrt{y}$, which technically could happen, nothing wrong about that, but it might be the reason why the sum diverges.

Comment: I also thought that the wrong-ness would be in substitution. However, I still can't understand why is it because because variables reach same value of limit. Can you elaborate more in the answer. Thanks

Comment: @An_Elephant Your substitution for $x$ is fine since $\sqrt{x}\rightarrow\infty$ so $x\rightarrow\infty$, but when you change the index of the sum from $y=1$ to $\sqrt{y}=1$ you actually get more terms.

Answer (score 1):

you could verify below equation using Taylor's expansion

$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty{1\over r^2}=-\int_{0}^1{{ln(1-x)\over x}dx}$$

by substituting  $$ln(1-x)=z$$

we get,
$$=\int_0^\infty \frac{z}{e^z-1}dz$$

which is called ***BOSE INTEGRAL***
and it is solved using *complex analysis*

a useful [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472687/prove-int-infty-0-frac-xex-1dx-frac-pi26) for solving the same problem

Comment: But how did you convert it into that integral?

Comment: You can directly get that integral by inverse Laplace transforming the 1/r^2 lol

Comment: But I asked for limit as a sum method. Anyway, thanks. Are you potato?

Comment: @An_Elephant In high school ( 3 months ago ) i noticed relation between $ln(1-x)$ and and $1\over r$ summation so , i manuplated it in above form for $1\over r^2$.

Comment: @CaptainChicky that would be simpler if the reader knows Laplace transform.

Comment: @An_Elephant I am Ice Bear aka Potato

Comment: @CaptainPotato Ok. But I was asking that to captain chicky.