# Generating function of the polylogarithm.

Tags: special-functions, generating-functions, closed-form, polylogarithm

Let $\operatorname{Li}_s(z)$ denote the polylogarithm function
$$\operatorname{Li}_s(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k^s}.$$

Does there exists a closed form or a known function which generates the polylogarithm on powers of the order $s$? I mean How to formulate $G$ such that

$$G(x,z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \operatorname{Li}_n(z) x^n$$
or the exponential generating function for the polylogarithm
$$G(x,z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\operatorname{Li}_n(z)}{n!}x^n$$
instead?

For example we know for $z=1$ and starting from a higher order, its generating function  is Digamma, as shown in [Generating functions and the Riemann Zeta Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/402988/622884)

Comment: Your polylogarithm does not depend on $n$.

Comment: If you substitute $$
{\rm Li}_n (z) = \frac{z}{{\Gamma (n)}}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{t^{n - 1} }}{{{\rm e}^t  - z}}{\rm d}t}
$$ for $n\geq 1$ and change the order of summation and integration, you obtain a representation in terms of the modified Bessel function: $$
z\sqrt x \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{t^{ - 1/2} }}{{{\rm e}^t  - z}}I_1 (2\sqrt {xt} ){\rm d}t}  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{\rm Li}_n (z)}}{{n!}}x^n } .
$$

Comment: You should have posted it as an answer! although such form is not so closed and it would need a bit more of simplification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing $|z|<1$ and that we have the right to reverse the order of the series we get :
\begin{align}
G(x,z)&:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k^n} x^n\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty z^k \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac xk\right)^n\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{1-\frac xk},\quad\text{for $x\not\in \mathbb{N}$}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k\;z^k}{k-x},\quad\text{for $x\not\in \mathbb{N}$}\\
&= z\frac d{dz}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k-x},\quad\text{for $x\not\in \mathbb{N}$}\\
&= z\frac d{dz}\left(z\,\Phi(z, 1, 1-x)\right),\quad\text{for $x\not\in \mathbb{N}$}\\
&= z\left(\frac1{1-z}+x\,\Phi(z, 1, 1-x)\right),\quad\text{for $x\not\in \mathbb{N}$}\\
\end{align}
using the [Lerch zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function) $\displaystyle\;\Phi(z, s, \alpha) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac { z^n} {(n+\alpha)^s}$

Your second generating function appears not so easy :
\begin{align}
H(x,z)&:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\operatorname{Li}_n(z)}{n!}x^n\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty z^k \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1{n!}\left(\frac xk\right)^n\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty z^k \exp{\frac xk}\\
\end{align}
but it seems that Gary already provided an answer!

Comment: Yes indeed also I obtained this formula for the factorial version, but I have not been able to simplify it.

Comment: Well, the formula provided by Gary is not really simple (even if there is a long list of nearly similar integrals producing Bessel functions). Another idea could be rewrite my last formula as a PDE. Anyway the first $G$ function is simpler and you may omit the $\frac z{1-z}$ term if you start at $n=1$. Excellent continuation,

Comment: Another integral expression would be taking @gary 's approach to the first version, and $e^z$ as the generating function of the reciprocal of the factorial, and then apply the [termwise Hadamard product of two generating functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3526636/622884).

Comment: An integral expression for the factorial version is obtained from substituting the Laurent series of the exponential function centered and evaluated at zero,
$$\frac{1}{n!}=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint \frac{e^u}{u^{1+n}}du,$$
in the second version:
$$H(x,z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\operatorname{Li}_n(z)}{n!}x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint \frac{e^u}{u^{1+n}}du \operatorname{Li}_n(z)x^n=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \operatorname{Li}_n(z) (\frac{x}{u})^n e^u \frac{du}{u}$$ thus $$H(x,z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint G(\frac{x}{u},z) e^u \frac{du}{u}.$$

Comment: @DrPotato: well you may put all this in an answer and add all the details you'll find relevant (self-answers are recommended at SE!). Excellent continuation,

Comment: For now we have that one. If someone else comes up with a closed form of it I will really appreciate it and change the right answer to that one!

Comment: Nevertheless, it seems to equal zero: For simplicity, following the same procedure but changing $\operatorname{Li}_n$ by $\operatorname{Li}_{1+n}$  leads to
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{Li_{1+n}(z)}{n!} x^n =\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint e^u \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k+1-\frac{x}{u}} \frac{du}{u}$$
By the Residue Theorem this would equal the same as approximating to $u=0$ in the other integrand factor than $\frac{du}{u}$, which tends to have an $-\infty$ denominator! Where am I wrong in this reasoning? Is it not possible to change the order of integration and summation in this case ..or what?