# How to derive this infinite product for gamma function

Tags: gamma-function

I am familiar with the weierstrass infinite product and eulers form yet I'm clueless as to how to derive this infinite product formula below.

$$\Gamma(1+z)=\frac 1{e^{\gamma z}}\sqrt{\frac {\pi z}{\sin\pi z}}\prod\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-\frac {\zeta(2k+1)z^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\right)$$

Comment: Simplify the exponential product into the exponential of a series. If you differentiate that series, you’re left with the odd terms of a known generating function, which you can extract. It’s a good idea to try something on MSE, any working or thoughts at all

Comment: Cool thx I'll see how far I get

Comment: I took logarithm of both sides

Comment: So ur saying I should take derivative of ln gamma

Comment: I made a mistake. While $\zeta(2n)$ in the product would have a known evaluation, $\zeta(2n+1)$ is less-known (famously). This will require some other trickery then!

Comment: So I got an expression for digamma (z+1) from the formula above . But I've never seen this expression for digamma

Comment: Please don't post equations as images here—it makes searching the site harder, for example.

Comment: The digamma function, as I have just learned, is a generator for all the values of the zeta function, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/402988/815585)

Comment: @GregMartin thank you for pointing it out .

Answer (score 2):

[Weierstrass's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Weierstrass%27s_definition) $\Gamma(1+z)=z\Gamma(z)=e^{-\gamma z}\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+z/n)^{-1}e^{z/n}$ gives, for $\color{red}{|z|<1}$, $$\log\Gamma(1+z)=-\gamma z+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac{z}{n}-\log\left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)\right]
\\=-\gamma z+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac1k\left(-\frac{z}{n}\right)^k=-\gamma z+\sum_{k=2}^\infty\zeta(k)\frac{(-z)^k}{k}.$$

The even part of this series (that is, the sum of terms with even $k$) is then $$\frac12\big(\log\Gamma(1+z)+\log\Gamma(1-z)\big)=\frac12\log\frac{\pi z}{\sin\pi z}$$ by the reflection formula, hence $\log\Gamma(1+z)$ is this quantity plus the odd part: $$\log\Gamma(1+z)=-\gamma z+\frac12\log\frac{\pi z}{\sin\pi z}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\zeta(2k+1)\frac{z^{2k+1}}{2k+1}.$$